# show vat in report but not in frontend

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I want to apply 20% vat. For that I already add 20% price to every product.But I want to show 20% vat in report in admin. Is there is any way to show 20% vat report in admin without applying vat in frontend.

Answer (score 0):

VAT = PRICE * (VAT percentage/100)

20% VAT for $120:  $120 * 0.2 = $24

In your product class have one property for price excluding VAT and another property for price including VAT.

Comment: I set tax class "None" as I don't want to show vat in frontend but want to show in report generated in admin. Please help me how can I do it.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can do this with standard Magento